# Filling a https login form

Tags: android, email

I am developing an app which simply opens my office mail inbox in the browser. The application will fetch the user name and password. It needs to fire a login request with the same and the mail page should open in the browser. The login page is https OWA. Which function do I use for   framing this https request...

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: The problem is I have no idea what to try. when I started I thought I can pass the username and password along with the url. but failed to realise that they are not sent during an https session.